# Get the position of a split window inside of vim

Tags: vim-windows

Is there any way to get the position of the top left corner of a split window relative to the entire vim window? For example, if there was only one window, and the tabline was inactive, the position would be 1,1. But, if the tabline was active, and there was another split window that was 10 characters wide to the left of the current window, the position would be 11,2. Is there any way to figure this out?

Comment: `:h win_screenpos()`

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matt mentioned in a comment, `win_screenpos(window number)` returns a list with the x and y position of the window.